# join by concatenating custom day/month to a provided year

Tags: sql, db2

I am using sql db2 to join two tables for people moving house by date, however I only have the year provided in one of the tables:

```
select a.person,b.from_date,b.to_date,a.year from table1
join
table2
on a.person = b.person
and a.year between year(b.from_dt) and year(b.to_dt)
```

But I want to add "1st January" onto a.year in the last line. (b.from_dt and b.to_dt are full dates)

Is there a way I concat the year and my custom day/month? At the moment I am bringing back duplicates so it would read *something* like

```
and a.year'01-01' between b.from_dt and b.to_dt
```

thanks!

Comment: What's the column datatype that holds the year?

Comment: @James Crawshaw - it's an integer

Answer (score 0):

This logic comes close to what you want:

```
a.year between year(b.from_dt) + 1 and year(b.to_dt)
```

The one day that it misses is when `b.from_dt` is January 1st.  In many applications, this would not make a difference, because that is a holiday.

If that is an issue, you can test for it directly:

```
(a.year > year(b.from_dt) or
 (a.year = year(b.from_dt) and month(b.from_dt) = 1 and day(b.from_dt = 1)
) and a.year >= year(b.to_dt)
```

You can also start doing string manipulations, but you can also do this with integer arithmetic:

```
a.year*10000+101 between year(b.from_dt)*10000+month(b.from_dt)*100+day(b.from_dt) and
                         year(b.to_dt)*10000+month(b.to_dt)*100+day(b.to_dt);
```

Comment: replacing a.year with a.year*10000+101 does work, however yields an empty table. somehow i don't think the '10000+101' is translated as "1st januaray"

Comment: I was assuming that `a.year` is a number not a dt.  Otherwise, you could just use `trunc(a.year, 'year')` to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with DB2, but have looked at a bit of documentation and maybe something like this would work...

```
select a.person,b.from_date,b.to_date,a.year from table1
join
table2
on a.person = b.person
and to_date((CAST (a.year AS VARCHAR(4)) CONCAT '0101'),'YYYYMMDD' ) between b.from_dt and b.to_dt
```

The to_date function appears to take in a string of a certain format and output a date, so if we convert the integer year from a.year to a string and then concatenate 0101 for the first of Jan, we should be able to feed that in the to_date function.